# how can i group the ouput in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a schedule. By selecting the date, I will have to display by company all the products that expire at that moment, let's take for example these two databases:

Company `DB`:

```
+------------+-----------+
| id_company | name      |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          | Microsoft |
+------------+-----------+
| 2          | Apple     |
+------------+-----------+
| 3          | IBM       |
+------------+-----------+
```

Products `DB`:

```
+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| id_products | id_pro_company | name_products | control_dates |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1           | 1              | pc            | 2020-10-02    |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2           | 2              | tablet        | 2020-10-10    |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
| 3           | 3              | phone         | 2030-10-10    |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM products as p JOIN company as c on c.id_company = p.id_pro_company and p.control_dates LIKE ?
```

Now i have all record i need, but how can i group the ouput in php.
example:

```
$date = '%2020-10%';
$query = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT * FROM products as p JOIN company as c on c.id_company = p.id_pro_company and p.control_dates LIKE ?');
$query -> bind_param('s',$date);
$query -> execute();
$result = $query -> get_result();
if($result -> num_rows > 0){
   //how group for company then for products then output the record?
}else{
    echo 'Nothing to do';
}
```

As you can see in the comment in the code I don't understand how to group companies with products inside.

Example output:

```
 1. Microsoft
    - PC
      * 1 - pc - 2020-10-02
 
 2. Apple
    -tablet
      * 2 - tablet - 2020-10-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with mysl you will always get a flat array (so data will be repeated) so the idea would be to do nested foreach on the same array: the first will output the vendor, the second with an if on the vendor will echo the product type and the third will echo the products. But this is very unefficient.

I'd go for something like three different queries: find vendors, find product type and find products.

Third way is to manipulate your array to split it into different arrays for each vendor but this is yet less efficient compared to multiple queries IMHO

Comment: So create a query and foreach it and create a second foreach with another query for each products ?

Comment: yes, you loop the vendors and inside you have the query for the rpoducts. In the second query you pass the vendor in the where clause so that you will get only the relevant data. Note that in the vendor query you should anyway join the product table to get only the vendors you want to display and not all the vendors.

Comment: I try and let you know for now thanks.

Comment: Done. grazie ;)